# how to pass value to abstract class for changing name property

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, abstract-class

I had an interview today and it had the following code with 2 questions. Could someone please help me answer the two questions below on the below code snippet. *(Some minor syntax error if seen please ignore as I tried to remember it from mind)....*

**Question 1 - Change the name  to "NameChange".**

**Question 2 - Override the abstract method in derived class.**

```
public abstract Class A
{
    public string Name { get { return GetName(); } };
    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return this.Name.ToString();
    }

    protected abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public class B : A
{
     //Change name to "NameChange"

     //override the abstract method here
}
```

Comment: I think there's a `StackOverflow` exception going around that code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should answer both questions:

```
public class B : A
{
    //override Method
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "NameChange";
    }

    // override abstract Method
    protected override void SomeMethod()
    {
        //code here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah pretty much. If OP recalled the question correctly from the interview, this is the likely answer.

Comment: @LiorBenisty: It is exactly what I wanted. I wrote the same answer as you for the 2nd question but first question I wrote like  - base("NameChange" and interviewer asked me how long I was not coding and I replied for last one year i worked as a BA and never touched code :)

Comment: @LiorBenisty: What I liked in your answer is, you didn't write anything but answered "To the point" which impressed me. Although Camilo did write his similar answers first but a bit of confusion and some more points (valuable observations) he had in his reply

Comment: @Learner It was my plassure.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure whether there's a hidden question or those are as simple as this. For the first question, there're two answers (method 1 and 2):

```
public class B : A
{
    //Method 1
    public new string Name { get { return "NameChange"; } }

    //Method 2
    public override string GetName()
    {
        return "NameChange"; // return whatever you want
    }

    protected override void SomeMethod() // override abstract method
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In Method 1, you are effectively *hiding* the implementation of `Name` of the base class. In Method 2, you are *overriding* the implementation of `GetName`.

Comment: Thank you so much, brilliant. Your answer helped me a lot and youw ere first too, but given that your first method confuses me and also your infinite loop point although is very respected but I think we can ignore my small syntax errors if any...but your method 2 was right answer and the override is great too for 2nd question... Thank you so much again.

Comment: @Learner You should read about the difference between hiding and overriding, it's part of the basics of OOP. Glad it answered your doubts, though.

Comment: Thank you again, I appreciate your effort to help me. From my instinct, I feel your method 2 is more easy or appropriate ( Doesn't mean your method 1 is unacceptable or wrong). As you see, even Lior answered same as you with method 2)

Comment: It's not that it's easier, they provoke different results. Method 1 removes the call to `GetName`, so if there's any child override, it won't be used. Method 2 removes the usage of the `Name` property, so both `Name.get` and `GetName()` return always the same.

Comment: I see, agree with you. But I think you do not have the provision to change the call to GetName directly :) Just my thoughts? in the context how you would see this question?

Comment: Overriding `GetName` would make most sense here, but to decide you'd need to know what the calling code is using (`Name.get` or `GetName()`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i get it right, but is that what you need?

```
public class B : A
{
    public string NameChange => base.GetName();

    protected override void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Or maybe this one?

```
public class B : A
{
   public override string GetName()
   {
       return "NameChange";
   }

   protected override void SomeMethod()
   {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the point here but if they insist on changing the value of property name, new constraint can be the trick here.

You can find the implementation following;

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string Name { get { return GetName(); } }

    public virtual string GetName()
    {
        return this.Name.ToString();
    }

    protected abstract void SomeMethod();
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() : base()
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }

    public new string Name { get; set; }

    public override string GetName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    protected override void SomeMethod()
    {
        this.Name = "Ayberk";
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Your code goes here
        B b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(b.GetName());
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](http://rextester.com/YJMSGG73025)